# Excel data upload into Postgres using C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am looking toinsert data from excel sheet into postgres db, using C#. COPY command wont work since it gives file not found error. What other options are available?

Comment: One of the options is Npgsql .NET Data Provider. It allows you to access a PostgreSQL database from any .NET application.

Comment: But still, I don't know why you have a file not found error. Can you elaborate? A file name instructs the PostgreSQL server to directly read from or write to a file. The file must be accessible to the server and the name must be specified from the viewpoint of the server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.